# Dismissing a view controller

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller

So i want to dismiss my modal view controller which i opened from app delegate. (Login screen for first time).

Now i am raising a notification when facebook sdk returns with success and calling

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

i get the error:

> Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!

A simple google search would suggest that i use

```
if (![[self modalViewController] isBeingDismissed])
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Now i cant change the code in FB SDK. And therefore i dont know when the modalViewController is fully dismissed. If i use the above code [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; will be skipped.

So is there a way to go around it without using timeDelay? Is there a function which will be raised after the modal is dismissed so i can dismiss my current Modal?

Comment: What do you mean it would *skip dismissing completely*? That conditional is only hit once, which allows the dismissal to occur. Please elaborate on your questions.

Comment: It's telling you that another view is being dismissed at the same time that you're trying to dismiss the modal view.  Is that true?  If so, you'll either need to dismiss the modal view in the `completion` block of the view that's currently being dismissed or send the notification in the `completion` block

Comment: @ArtSabintsev: Edited my Question to elaborate.

Comment: @iWasRobbed I dont have control over how the current modal view is called. I am using the singly iOS SDK. Therefore i dont have the completion block of the view. I have a delegate which gets called and thats when i have perform my stuff and dismiss the modal. Currently i am just calling the function to dismiss after some time delay and i was wondering if there is a workaround for that.